# How can to display a field of type LocalDate in my report?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans

I am using IReport-5.6.0 Plugin for NetBeans 8.0.2.

1. From the data preview , all the data is coming properly.
2. If I remove the field, all other data are coming correctly.
3. I have a field which is of java.sql.Date.
   When i run using Netbeans , i get the following errors:

How can to display this field in my report?.

```
    Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '2015-03-22' with class 'java.time.LocalDate' to class 'java.sql.Date'
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.DefaultTypeTransformation.castToType(DefaultTypeTransformation.java:360)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.castToType(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:599)
at null_1427308438299_735647.evaluate(calculator_null_1427308438299_735647:170)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:250)
... 77 more
```

the query part in my jrxml:

```
<queryString language="SQL">
            <![CDATA[SELECT
         USER."NAME" AS name,
         USER."EMAIL" AS email,
         USER."BIRTHDAY" AS birthday
    FROM
         "PUBLIC"."USER" USER]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="name" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="email" class="java.lang.String"/>
        <field name="birthday" class="java.sql.Date"/>
```

My java class has the following method:

```
private void printOut(ActionEvent event) throws JRException {
    String report = "report1.jrxml";
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(data); 
    JasperReport jas_rep = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(report) ;
    JasperPrint jas_prin = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jas_rep,null,beanCollectionDataSource);
    JasperViewer.viewReport(jas_prin);
}
```

Comment: You should define the fields in report and at the bean identically

Comment: @AlexK: you are right. i did the following modification : <field name="birthday" class="java.time.LocalDate"/>. It works. I want to format the field birthday of type LocalDate in my report. How can I do that using Expression editor. I use : $F{birthday}.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy")), but I get an Exception

Comment: I found the solution. $F{birthday}.format( java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"))